# AWS Athena CREATE TABLE An error occurred (InvalidRequestException) when calling the StartQueryExecution mismatched input 'EXTERNAL'. Expecting

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-athena, amazon-sagemaker, amazon-sagemaker-studio

I am trying to create a table via AWS Athena and getting the following error:

```
An error occurred (InvalidRequestException) when calling the StartQueryExecution operation: line 1:8: mismatched input 'EXTERNAL'. Expecting: 'OR', 'SCHEMA', 'TABLE', 'VIEW'
unable to rollback
```

Here is the statement it tries to execute which begets this error:

```
# SQL statement to execute
statement = """CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS {}.{}(
         incident_id string,
         incident_date date,
         state string,
         city_or_county string,
         address string,
         n_killed int,
         n_injured int,
         incident_url string,
         source_url string,
         incident_url_fields_missing int string,
         congressional_district int,
         gun_stolen string,
         gun_type string,
         incident_characteristics string,
         latitude float,
         location_description string,
         longitude float,
         n_guns_involved int,
         notes string,
         participant_age string,
         participant_age_group string,
         participant_gender string,
         participant_name string,
         participant_relationship string,
         participant_status string,
         participant_type string,
         sources string,
         state_house_district int,
         state_senate_district int
) ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' LINES TERMINATED BY '\\n' LOCATION '{}'
""".format(
    database_name, table_name_csv, s3_private_path_csv
)

import pandas as pd

pd.read_sql(statement, conn)
```

If I run a print(statement) you get this:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS dsoaws.gun_violence_csv2(
     incident_id varchar(10),
     incident_date date,
     state varchar(25),
     city_or_county varchar(25),
     address string,
     n_killed int,
     n_injured int,
     incident_url string,
     source_url string,
     incident_url_fields_missing int string,
     congressional_district int,
     gun_stolen string,
     gun_type string,
     incident_characteristics string,
     latitude float,
     location_description string,
     longitude float,
     n_guns_involved int,
     notes string,
     participant_age string,
     participant_age_group string,
     participant_gender string,
     participant_name string,
     participant_relationship string,
     participant_status string,
     participant_type string,
     sources string,
     state_house_district int,
     state_senate_district int
) ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' LOCATION 's3://sagemaker-studio-898900188658-v9o4cft4fj/gun-violence'
TBLPROPERTIES ('skip.header.line.count'='1')
```

I am pretty sure it has to do with the column types being declared.  Per the documentation, it doesn't seem to me that the float type isn't allowed.  (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/data-types.html)

Per Athena documentation, the dates are in the right format YYYY-MM-DD.

Is there any problem with the fields being set to string?  I used it as a general one just to try to get the table working.

I have also checked other stackoverflow articles and ensured that the database name and table name are not using any hyphens.
db name: dsoaws
table name: gun_violence_csv

As reference, the dataset is available here:
https://github.com/jamesqo/gun-violence-data
https://github.com/jamesqo/gun-violence-data/blob/master/DATA_01-2013_03-2018.tar.gz?raw=true

UPDATED here is the query result:

```
    Failed to execute query.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyathena/common.py", line 305, in _execute
    **request
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyathena/util.py", line 84, in retry_api_call
    return retry(func, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tenacity/__init__.py", line 379, in __call__
    do = self.iter(retry_state=retry_state)
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tenacity/__init__.py", line 314, in iter
    return fut.result()
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/concurrent/futures/_base.py", line 428, in result
    return self.__get_result()
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/concurrent/futures/_base.py", line 384, in __get_result
    raise self._exception
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tenacity/__init__.py", line 382, in __call__
    result = fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/botocore/client.py", line 357, in _api_call
    return self._make_api_call(operation_name, kwargs)
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/botocore/client.py", line 676, in _make_api_call
    raise error_class(parsed_response, operation_name)
botocore.errorfactory.InvalidRequestException: An error occurred (InvalidRequestException) when calling the StartQueryExecution operation: line 1:8: mismatched input 'EXTERNAL'. Expecting: 'OR', 'SCHEMA', 'TABLE', 'VIEW'
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
InvalidRequestException                   Traceback (most recent call last)
/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyathena/common.py in _execute(self, operation, parameters, work_group, s3_staging_dir, cache_size, cache_expiration_time)
    304                     logger=_logger,
--> 305                     **request
    306                 ).get("QueryExecutionId", None)

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyathena/util.py in retry_api_call(func, config, logger, *args, **kwargs)
     83     )
---> 84     return retry(func, *args, **kwargs)

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tenacity/__init__.py in __call__(self, fn, *args, **kwargs)
    378         while True:
--> 379             do = self.iter(retry_state=retry_state)
    380             if isinstance(do, DoAttempt):

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tenacity/__init__.py in iter(self, retry_state)
    313         if not (is_explicit_retry or self.retry(retry_state)):
--> 314             return fut.result()
    315 

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/concurrent/futures/_base.py in result(self, timeout)
    427             elif self._state == FINISHED:
--> 428                 return self.__get_result()
    429 

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/concurrent/futures/_base.py in __get_result(self)
    383         if self._exception:
--> 384             raise self._exception
    385         else:

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tenacity/__init__.py in __call__(self, fn, *args, **kwargs)
    381                 try:
--> 382                     result = fn(*args, **kwargs)
    383                 except BaseException:  # noqa: B902

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/botocore/client.py in _api_call(self, *args, **kwargs)
    356             # The "self" in this scope is referring to the BaseClient.
--> 357             return self._make_api_call(operation_name, kwargs)
    358 

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/botocore/client.py in _make_api_call(self, operation_name, api_params)
    675             error_class = self.exceptions.from_code(error_code)
--> 676             raise error_class(parsed_response, operation_name)
    677         else:

InvalidRequestException: An error occurred (InvalidRequestException) when calling the StartQueryExecution operation: line 1:8: mismatched input 'EXTERNAL'. Expecting: 'OR', 'SCHEMA', 'TABLE', 'VIEW'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

DatabaseError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/io/sql.py in execute(self, *args, **kwargs)
   1696         try:
-> 1697             cur.execute(*args, **kwargs)
   1698             return cur

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyathena/util.py in _wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
     36         with _lock:
---> 37             return wrapped(*args, **kwargs)
     38 

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyathena/cursor.py in execute(self, operation, parameters, work_group, s3_staging_dir, cache_size, cache_expiration_time)
     93             cache_size=cache_size,
---> 94             cache_expiration_time=cache_expiration_time,
     95         )

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyathena/common.py in _execute(self, operation, parameters, work_group, s3_staging_dir, cache_size, cache_expiration_time)
    308                 _logger.exception("Failed to execute query.")
--> 309                 raise DatabaseError(*e.args) from e
    310         return query_id

DatabaseError: An error occurred (InvalidRequestException) when calling the StartQueryExecution operation: line 1:8: mismatched input 'EXTERNAL'. Expecting: 'OR', 'SCHEMA', 'TABLE', 'VIEW'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

NotSupportedError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/io/sql.py in execute(self, *args, **kwargs)
   1700             try:
-> 1701                 self.con.rollback()
   1702             except Exception as inner_exc:  # pragma: no cover

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyathena/connection.py in rollback(self)
    241     def rollback(self) -> None:
--> 242         raise NotSupportedError

NotSupportedError: 

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

DatabaseError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-35-098d263441f4> in <module>
      1 import pandas as pd
      2 
----> 3 pd.read_sql(statement, conn)

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/io/sql.py in read_sql(sql, con, index_col, coerce_float, params, parse_dates, columns, chunksize)
    488             coerce_float=coerce_float,
    489             parse_dates=parse_dates,
--> 490             chunksize=chunksize,
    491         )
    492 

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/io/sql.py in read_query(self, sql, index_col, coerce_float, params, parse_dates, chunksize)
   1741 
   1742         args = _convert_params(sql, params)
-> 1743         cursor = self.execute(*args)
   1744         columns = [col_desc[0] for col_desc in cursor.description]
   1745 

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/io/sql.py in execute(self, *args, **kwargs)
   1704                     f"Execution failed on sql: {args[0]}\n{exc}\nunable to rollback"
   1705                 )
-> 1706                 raise ex from inner_exc
   1707 
   1708             ex = DatabaseError(f"Execution failed on sql '{args[0]}': {exc}")

DatabaseError: Execution failed on sql: CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS dsoaws.gun_violence_csv2(
         incident_id varchar(10),
         incident_date date,
         state varchar(25),
         city_or_county varchar(25),
         address string,
         n_killed int,
         n_injured int,
         incident_url string,
         source_url string,
         incident_url_fields_missing int string,
         congressional_district int,
         gun_stolen string,
         gun_type string,
         incident_characteristics string,
         latitude float,
         location_description string,
         longitude float,
         n_guns_involved int,
         notes string,
         participant_age string,
         participant_age_group string,
         participant_gender string,
         participant_name string,
         participant_relationship string,
         participant_status string,
         participant_type string,
         sources string,
         state_house_district int,
         state_senate_district int
) ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' LOCATION 's3://sagemaker-studio-898900188658-v9o4cft4fj/gun-violence'
TBLPROPERTIES ('skip.header.line.count'='1')
An error occurred (InvalidRequestException) when calling the StartQueryExecution operation: line 1:8: mismatched input 'EXTERNAL'. Expecting: 'OR', 'SCHEMA', 'TABLE', 'VIEW'
unable to rollback
```

Comment: Could you post the query after the string interpolation?

Comment: Just updated the post with the result of a print(statement).

Comment: @jellycsc Also just posted the query result

Comment: `incident_url_fields_missing int string,` you declared two types here

Comment: I read your reply and thought "damnit!"  it's always the simple things I fail to check first.  I was oggling over the data types...the data is loading now.  as an experienced programmer, are the simple things the first thing you check for in your code?

Comment: I'm glad to hear it's working now. Athena error message sucks in most of the times. Since I encountered this kind of issue many times, the first thing I do is to check for typos in the query.

Answer (score 1):

According to OP's feedback, the issue is in the following line

```
incident_url_fields_missing int string,
```

where two conflicting types are declared for the `incident_url_fields_missing` column.